# validity of oauth_token over time and linkedin API

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

I used the following code from linkedin:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide#toggleview:id=php

It shows how to get an access token and generate the typical authenticate url in php:
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxx

Here is the issue: when I copy paste the url, it works at first: I get to the linkedIn page to
 authorize the access. However, if I try the same link, i.e the same token after 5 minutes, I get the error: "We were unable to find the authorization token".
I have tried several time with different token and get the same result: from the first time is generated and up to 5 minutes later, the url works, and then after 5 minutes, I get the error page.
I'd appreciate some suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the oAuth 'dance' is the timestamp which has to be within 5 minutes of the first part of the dance. The slideshow http://www.slideshare.net/episod/linkedin-oauth-zero-to-hero may be helpful.